# Alias for relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :jobs
```

How can I rename ":jobs" to something else without renaming the source class? I just want to be to refer to them as:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :obligations
```

and that's it. I've tried:

```
has_many :obligations, source: :user
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Hey you can try with `has_many :obligations, :class_name =>Job`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing wrong. Instead of adding source add class like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :obligations,   class_name: 'Job'
end
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

> If the name of the other model cannot be derived from the association name, you can use the :class_name option to supply the model name.

you have to use `:class_name` option

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :obligations, class_name: 'Job'
end
```